# Send plain text in json format in an api webservice in coldfusion

Tags: json, api, coldfusion

I have an api I'm working on, I need to be able to send the coverletter of an applicant, which is stored like plain text in a table. I have a function which grabs the text as below. Do I have to use SerializeJSON(coverlettertext) before I return the text? In order for it to be consumed and get the proper data on the other end. Please advice.

```
<cffunction name="query1" access="remote" returnformat="JSON" output="true">
<cfquery name="local.cover_letter" datasource="#variables.dsn#">
                SELECT cover_letter
                  FROM table1
                 WHERE userid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="12345" />
                    AND jobid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="456" />
            </cfquery> 

                     <cfif local.get_cover_letter.recordCount>
                           <cfreturn local.cover_letter/>
                     </cfif>  
</cffunction>
```

Comment: It depends what the consuming function/service requires it to be. If it wants JSON then yes.

Comment: Since you have returnformat="JSON" in your parameters, then yes, you should use serializeJSON. Does your consumer expect JSON?

Comment: You shouldn't need `output="true"` in your function BTW, as it's not actually outputting anything, merely returning some JSON

Comment: @ChrisWillard returnformat="json" will do the serialization automatically, no need to call serializeJson yourself.

Answer (score 4):

ColdFusion functions with returnFormat, serializes it for you, but its ColdFusions format of Serialize.. it would take a returned query or struct, and serialize it as it sees fit. This is not always the expected format, as it has one row of cols, then several rows of data... compared to colnames and values in each and every row (CF11 allows you to select the serializing format or right your own but only if you call it manually I believe). 
So you could say the return type is query, and then the format is json, and it will do it for you... it will be JSON, will it work with the service you're using, that DEPENDS on what the other end is EXPECTING.

If you require it in a specific format, ie, not ColdFusions, then you would want to change the ReturnFormat to plain, and then return a string, encoded how you want to.

Answer (score 1):

From the context of your question, I'm assuming that you are only getting 1 letter.  If I'm mistaken, then that would alter my response.  That said, +1 to Gavin for identifying that the format will be different from what you may expect if you serialize the query object.  You can instead, make a CF struct out of the output that you want and then serialize that.  Take a look at the two variants in the code below.

As everyone else has noted, it all depends on what the consumer of the service is expecting.

```
<cffunction name="query1" access="remote" returnformat="JSON" output="true">
    <cfscript>
        local.cover_letter = queryNew(
        "cover_letter",
        "varChar",
        [
            {
            cover_letter:"This is the text of my letter.  It could be much longer"
            }
        ]

        );
    </cfscript>

    <cfif local.cover_letter.recordCount>
        <cfreturn serializeJson(local.cover_letter)/>
    </cfif>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="query2" access="remote" returnformat="JSON" output="true">
    <cfscript>
        local.cover_letter = queryNew(
        "cover_letter",
        "varChar",
        [
            {
            cover_letter:"This is the text of my letter.  It could be much longer"
            }
        ]
        );
    </cfscript>
    <cfif local.cover_letter.recordCount>
        <cfset local.str = {cover_letter= local.cover_letter.cover_letter} >
        <cfreturn serializeJson(local.str) />
    </cfif>
</cffunction>

<cfoutput>
<h1>query1 output</h1>
#query1()#
<h1>query2 output</h1>
#query2()#
</cfoutput>
```

You output should be:

query1 output

{"COLUMNS":["COVER_LETTER"],"DATA":[["This is the text of my letter. It could be much longer"]]}

query2 output

{"COVER_LETTER":"This is the text of my letter. It could be much longer"}